# Latest purchase date per category & month - Power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

Let's assume I have the below dataset:

[image]

How can I get the latest purchase date per item and month only for those items that >0?

Expected result:

[image]

I've tried a few solutions, one of them, but I cannot figure out all three conditions to be met:

```
latest_purchase_date = CALCULATE(
        MAX(tbl[date]),
        FILTER(ALL(tbl),
tbl[quantity]<>0))
```

Error:

[image]

Error:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Did you try the following:

```
VAR currMonth = MONTH(SELECTEDVALUE(tbl[date]))
VAR currYear = YEAR(SELECTEDVALUE(tbl[date]))
VAR currItem = SELECTEDVALUE(tbl[item])

RETURN 
    CALCULATE (
        MAX(tbl[date]),
        FILTER(
            ALL(tbl),
            tbl[quantity]<>0 && 
            tbl[item] = currItem && 
            MONTH(tbl[date]) = currMonth && 
            YEAR(tbl[date]) = currYear
        )
   )
```

Comment: @PratikBhavsar and Rado, thank you for the response, it throws the error next to the affirmation sign - see the updated response.

Comment: @eponkratova sorry being a c# developer, I wrote c# syntax :P.
You can just replace the double (==) with a single (=).

Comment: @PratikBhavsar, nope, it doesn't work. If I replace with a single =, it shows the evaluation error - see the updated response.

Comment: @eponkratova I have updated the measure in my answer, please try.

Comment: @PratikBhavsar, nope, it shows the error I put in the original posting.

Comment: @eponkratova can you post the calculated column formula?

Comment: @PratikBhavsar lat = VAR currMonth = MONTH(SELECTEDVALUE(purchases_in_between[date])) VAR currYear = YEAR(SELECTEDVALUE(purchases_in_between[date])) VAR currItem = SELECTEDVALUE(purchases_in_between[item_code]) RETURN CALCULATE ( MAX(purchases_in_between[date]), FILTER(ALL(purchases_in_between), purchases_in_between[purchased]<>0) && purchases_in_between[item_code] =currItem && MONTH(purchases_in_between[date]) =currMonth && YEAR(purchases_in_between[date]) = currYear )